# Is it possible to link to a specific portion of a Vimeo video?

Tags: vimeo

I would like to share a link to a Vimeo video and have it queue to a specific frame for beginning playback.

Specifically, I would like to point out the Loss Aversion section of the [Everything is a Remix](http://www.everythingisaremix.info/) video and have people start watching at 3 minutes and 28 seconds to [hilight the discussion on Intellectual Property and Loss Aversion](http://vimeo.com/36881035)

Is it possible to generally link to Vimeo videos while picking an arbitrary start point? If not, what workarounds are available whether it's an embed, or other means to reduce the effort for people to get to a specific point in a video. I'd rather not have to edit the footage directly and host it elsewhere.

Comment: Info on their forums is more than a year old, but it seems it's not possible due to the technology they are using—progressive download instead of streaming. See [this](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:21272) thread.

Comment: Thank you very much - I've re-asked the [question on vimeo's feature request forum](https://vimeo.com/forums/feature_requests/topic:49396) since two years is a _long_ time on a web service and perhaps there is a technical solution closer to implementation today.

Comment: @Alex that could be also the answer to this question. It's simply not possible, you can verify it but clicking on the seek bar on the part that wasn't loaded yet.. and you'll realize that even manually it's not possible

Comment: It's a two click operation for me on the Safari browser without flash loaded. First you click the play control, then you click in the seek bar at the correct place. Ugly, cumbersome, but that's why I had hoped to have a shortcut or some automation.

Comment: Yes -- you can do this online at http://www.vimeotime.com

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Appending `#t=0m0s` to the URL to point 0 minutes and 0 seconds past the start of the video.

Replace the `0`s with your desired values and the link will scrub forward the specified amount in your browser.

---

Although this wasn't a feature when I asked the question, Vimeo now supports this across the board.

The forum post with the announcement of this feature and an example of how to link to a moment inside a linked video:

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:49396

Basically, by appending `#t=1m5s` you can request the playhead be moved to one minute (1m) and five seconds (5s) of the video, so in the case of my question, the URL would be `#t=3m28s`:

http://vimeo.com/36881035#t=3m28s

Comment: Note: you need to click on a link for this to work (just editing the URL and pressing the `enter` key won't work).

Comment: eeeeyeah. This doesn't actually work at all. I have tried IE, Chrome and Firefox and multiple machines. Vimeo does not provide streaming or random-access to the posted videos, FLAT.

Comment: Works also on [ustream](http://www.ustream.tv).

Answer (score 0):

****Acctually this works for some browsers but not all..**

*** This is the correct way!*

This is fairly easy to do in Internet Explorer ie8+. All you have to do is select your video then right-click and copy url with timestamp. Other browser might not give you the copy url.

So all this is adding this to the end of url #t=89 where t=seconds into video. In my example **1m29s** into the video

Example https://vimeo.com/5003279#t=89